Scraping a website with dynamic javascript using beautiful soup
I am trying to the IBM docs. The following is the URL that I am looking at. I am wondering how to expand all the toggles on the left hand pane programatically so that I can get all the URLs and get the data.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/b2b-integrator/6.1.0
So seems like the RPA is the way to go, to expand each of the toggle button and expand it and scrape the data using Selenium like library.
But could anyone give any ideas?
Thanks and regards

Try:
import json
import requests

doc_url = "https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/toc/b2b-integrator/6.1.0?lang=en"


def print_topics(o, lvl=0):
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        print("\t" * lvl, o.get("label"), "->", o.get("href", ""))
        for t in o.get("topics", []):
            print_topics(t, lvl + 1)
    elif isinstance(o, list):
        for v in o:
            print_topics(v, lvl)


data = requests.get(doc_url).json()
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print_topics(data["toc"])

Prints:
 IBM Sterling B2B Integrator -> SS3JSW_6.1.0
     IBM Sterling B2B Integrator v6.1.0 documentation -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/kc_welcome_b2bi.html
     What's new in the release? -> 
         IBM Sterling B2B Integrator -> 
             What's new in 6.1.0.0 -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/whatsnew/whats_new/integrator/integrator_whats_new.html
                 What's new in 6.1.0.1 -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/whatsnew/whats_new/integrator/integrator_whats_new_6101.html
                 What's new in 6.1.0.3 -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/whatsnew/whats_new/integrator/integrator_whats_new_6103.html
                 What's new in 6.1.0.4 -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/whatsnew/whats_new/integrator/integrator_whats_new_6104.html
                 What's new in 6.1.0.5 -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/whatsnew/whats_new/integrator/integrator_whats_new_6105.html
                 What's new in 6.1.0.5_1 -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/whatsnew/whats_new/integrator/integrator_whats_new_6105_1.html
                 What's new in 6.1.0.5_2 -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/whatsnew/whats_new/integrator/integrator_whats_new_6105_2.html
                 What's new in 6.1.0.6 -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/whatsnew/whats_new/integrator/integrator_whats_new_6106.html
                 What's new in 6.1.0.7 -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/whatsnew/whats_new/integrator/integrator_whats_new_6107.html
                 What's new in 6.1.0.8 -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/whatsnew/whats_new/integrator/integrator_whats_new_6108.html
             What's deprecated -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/whatsnew/whats_new/integrator/integrator_whats_deprecated.html
                 What's deprecated in 6.1.0.1 -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/whatsnew/whats_new/integrator/integrator_whats_deprecated_6101.html
             Support policy for container delivery models -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/whatsnew/whats_new/integrator/integrator_support_policy.html
             Resolved issues -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/whatsnew/whats_new/integrator/integrator_resolved_issues.html
             Known issues -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/whatsnew/whats_new/integrator/integrator_known_issues.html
         IBM Global Mailbox -> 
             Known issues -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/whatsnew/whats_new/globalmailbox/gm_known_issues.html
     Release Notes -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/ReleaseNotes.html
     APAR Fixes -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/APAR_Fixes.html
     Quick Start Guide -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/QuickStartGuide.html
     Downloading installation media and components -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/IBMB2BIntegratorDownloadDoc.html
     Overview -> 
         IBM Sterling B2B Integrator Overview -> 
             System requirements -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/overview/overview/integrator/SI_system_requirements.html
             Sterling B2B Integrator overview -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/overview/overview/integrator/si_overview.html
                 Introduction to Sterling B2B Integrator -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/overview/overview/integrator/SI_Introduction.html
                     Evolving Business and Integration Objectives  -> SS3JSW_6.1.0/overview/overview/integrator/SI_EvolvBusIntObj.html

...

